# All strings table leads to PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am new to the pyspark and converting data types between python and spark. I want to transform a python list to pyspark dataframe but failed to do so. I searched the similar errors, but still cannot figure it out. Can someone provide guidance? Any help is appreciated.

I have created this list `output_list` as the output in databricks. The list looks like this:

```
[{'id': 'abcd342', 'v1': 'Mickey Mouse', 'v2': 'USA', 'v3': 'Male', 'v4': 'NY', 'v5': 'Artist', 'v6': 'Garden', 'v7': 'Donald', 'v8': 'Duck'}, 
 {'id': 'b4fcef', 'v1': 'Harry Potter', 'v2': 'Britain', 'v3': 'Male', 'v4': 'London', 'v5': 'Compliance Officer', 'v6': 'Dining Room', 'v7': 'Sally', 'v8': 'Human'}]
```

Then I tried to convert it to pyspark dataframe using the code below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType
from decimal import Decimal

appName = "Output results"
master = "local"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v2', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v3', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v4', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v5', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v6', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v7', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v8', StringType(), True)
])

# Convert list to RDD
output_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(output_list)

# Create data frame
output_df = spark.createDataFrame(output_rdd,schema)
print(output_df.schema)
print(type(output_df))
output_df.show()
```

Then I get the result including the error message like this:

```
output_df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
id:string
v1:string
v2:string
v3:string
v4:string
v5:string
v6:string
v7:string
v8:string
StructType(List(StructField(id,StringType,true),StructField(v1,StringType,true),StructField(v2,StringType,true),StructField(v3,StringType,true),StructField(v4,StringType,true),StructField(v5,StringType,true),StructField(v6,StringType,true),StructField(v7,StringType,true),StructField(v8,StringType,true)))
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 31.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 31.0 (TID 127) (10.201.235.14 executor 1): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-88414643813881> in <module>
     32 print(output_df.schema)
     33 print(type(output_df))
---> 34 output_df.show()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    488         """
    489         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 490             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    491         else:
    492             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306
```

What makes it weird is I tried another way to do the same process, and it works. I printed out the json like format list first, copid and pastet the list to a new variable. With this new variable, it transformed into pyspark dataframe without an issue. I checked the type of `output_list` and `output_list_2`, and both are `<class 'list'>`.  What should I change to make my original process work? Here is my test code:

```
output_list_2 = [{'id': 'abcd342', 'v1': 'Mickey Mouse', 'v2': 'USA', 'v3': 'Male', 'v4': 'NY', 'v5': 'Artist', 'v6': 'Garden', 'v7': 'Donald', 'v8': 'Duck'}, 
 {'id': 'b4fcef', 'v1': 'Harry Potter', 'v2': 'Britain', 'v3': 'Male', 'v4': 'London', 'v5': 'Compliance Officer', 'v6': 'Dining Room', 'v7': 'Sally', 'v8': 'Human'}]
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DecimalType
from decimal import Decimal

appName = "Output results"
master = "local"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v2', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v3', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v4', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v5', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v6', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v7', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v8', StringType(), True)
])

# Convert list to RDD
output_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(output_list_2)

# Create data frame
output_df = spark.createDataFrame(output_rdd,schema)
print(output_df.schema)
print(type(output_df))
output_df.show()
```

---

Still don't know why it wouldn't work. However, I find an alternative way to finish the work. Not perfect, but will do the job. Here is my solution:

```
# Create data frame
# *Old way*
# output_df = spark.createDataFrame(output_rdd,schema)
# print(output_df.schema)
# print(type(output_df))
# output_df.show()

# *New way*
output_df = sqlContext.read.json(output_rdd)
print(type(output_df))
output_df.show()
```

The catch is the order of the output. Since it does NOT use a schema, the columns are ordered alphabetically automatically.

Comment: Hi, do you have a hard reason why you have to create an RDD as an intermediate step to the Dataframe?

Comment: @BgRva Hi, I was following some examples to do so. I am open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your data like this, it is getting initialized as a list of *dictionaries*.

```
liet_1 = [{'id': 'abcd342', 'v1': 'Mickey Mouse'}, 
          {'id': 'b4fcef', 'v1': 'Harry Potter'}]
```

But, if you initialize the data as a list of **tuples** you can initialize the DataFrame directly, as long as the order of the items in each tuple are the same.  The schema will define the column names:

```
list_2 = [('abcd342', 'Mickey Mouse'), 
          ('b4fcef', 'Harry Potter')]

schema2 = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('v1', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(list_2, schema2 )
```

Cheers

Comment: Hi @BgRva, Thank you for the support. I updated my description in the question. The input is a list, not a json file. It just follows the same format `[{}, {}, ..., {}]` . Sorry for the earlier confusion. Could you provide advice based on this update?

Comment: I find an alternative way to achieve the goal. Not perfect, but working. Please see my update in the post. I still look forward to your input though. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was created in a list of dictionaries. It's quite confusing why it wouldn't work. But thank you so much for the discussion! It inspires.